# Deep link url define in debug Manifest is not working

Tags: android, navigation, android-manifest, deep-linking, android-deep-link

It was working fine till we have single Manifest file now we have created different Manifest for different build variant now deep link for debug variant not working. Please help me on this.Thanks
Here is the Manifest file for debug

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.app.myapp">

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AndroidAppUser.Default"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
           
          
            <intent-filter   android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="mydomain.com"
                    android:pathPattern="/.*" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```